# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 does not work

Tags: sql, excel

you may say that this has been asked before but I tried all the solutions around the web and here and none has resolved my issues.

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT * INTO [DB_Pack].[dbo].[Output_POL$]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=NO;
   Database=T:\Reports\Import\excelfile2.xlsx',
   [Output]);
```

And I get the following error:

```
Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' 
has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.
```

So far I have tried making the regedit changes as well as following this guide http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/enable-Ad-Hoc-Distributed-Queries.aspx

Does anyone have any further suggestions on how this issue can be solved.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx

Comment: Nick, I've enabled both options but I still get the error.

Comment: Perhaps you need to restart the SQL Server. Have you tried creating as a linked server just to try out that option?

Comment: Sorry I only just realised that the kodyaz link already mentions those adhoc settings. I'm sure that's it though....

Comment: I added the server and instant to the query and I get the following error now:

SELECT * INTO [server\instance].[DB_Pack].[dbo].[Output_POL$]

Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The object name 'server\instance.DB_Pack.dbo.Output_POL$' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Comment: I only just noticed the `INTO`. Just start simple... take the `INTO` out of the query - do you get a result? When I mentioned linked server I mean add the Excel source as a linked server, not the target table

Comment: When I take the INTO out I get the same error.

Comment: Now try to create the Excel source as a linked server. You'll either get a more meaningful error message or a workaround (you'll be able to reference the linked server instead of OPENROWSET)

Comment: Excel source is added, when I get the same error when I query it.

Comment: Linked servers did the job now we can pull the data from the Excel file but this can only be done locally, when performed via Management Studio from another computer the following error is received: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "EXCELMACRO" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "EXCELMACRO".

Comment: That's a lot of strange symptoms. I don't think I can help much further.